# Plot an array of spheres in VTK

Tags: c++, vtk

I want to use VTK in c++ and plot a molecule in 3D. I have a vector representing the positions  of atom and another vector representing size of each atom. How I can do this? Do I need to make a new sphere_source for each atom.

```
vector< vector <double> > Positions;
vector< double > Sizes;
```

Comment: I'd say a struct would be better option? say `struct Atom { double position; double size;};`  ??

Comment: Sure, my question is more about the VTK part, how to make array of objects; Do I need to make a lot of vtk spheres sources or there is mechanism inside VTK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at vtkGlyph3D, and this example:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Filtering/Glyph3D
However, you will need separate sphere source for each atom SIZE, all atoms having same size can use the same sphere source...

Comment: Thanks, I kinda did figure it out the same as you suggested.

Comment: Hi, this works perfect! Now, some idea in how to add a label on each glyph? I was trying with the vtkLabeledDataMapper, but no idea,

Answer (score 1):

```
void VTK_Plotter::Add_Point(vector<double> Position, double Size)
{

    Size = floor((log10(Size) + 0.2) * 100.0) / 100.0;

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> Current_Sphere_Source;
    // Different atomi number have different set of points
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> Current_Point_Group;
    // If the point has a size not in the list create a new sphere source with different size
    if (Table_Size_Source.find(Size) == Table_Size_Source.end()) {
        // Create new source
        Current_Sphere_Source = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();
        Current_Sphere_Source->SetRadius(Size);
        Table_Size_Source[Size] = Current_Sphere_Source;
        // Create new points
        Current_Point_Group = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
        Table_Points_VTK[Size] = Current_Point_Group;
    }
    else
    {
        Current_Sphere_Source = Table_Size_Source[Size];
        Current_Point_Group = Table_Points_VTK[Size];
    }
}
```